# How to use the phonegap inside the Xcode 1.5

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I have Mac mini with 10.3.9 OS I have downloaded Xcode 1.5 SDK for development.

I am very new in Iphone I don't know more about Iphone. **Can I write Iphone application Inside the this version of the XCODE 1.5**

I have searched on the Google for the reference link but not got any. My main concern is that can we write application for Iphone in Xcode 1.5 because  it is very old OS.

I have to use Phonegap but their they on their [site](http://phonegap.com/start) they have mention that for using the the phone gap 1.5 we have to use mac os leopard 10.6. so is their any lower version of phone gap available for Xcode 1.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, Xcode 3.1 was the first version to offer iOS development.

Comment: so before that their is no development available for the IOS. because I have MAC 10.3.9 panther so in that no IOS development possible.

Comment: @mayurrahatekar No, iOS wasn't around until 10.5.